# Python problem - Editing value in dictionary inside two dimensional list edits the whole matrix instead of only one item

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a matrix (two-dimensional list) filled with dictionary-type variable in the entire scope containing `"val": False`

The problem is when I want to change only one item in the matrix and chanhge the value to True for this one paticular item.

Somehow this part of code: `matrix[3][2]["val"] = True` causes the entire matrix to update the "val" value and changes all False values to True.

Here is my code:

```
defval = {
  "val": False
}

matrix = []

for x in range(5):
  row = []
  for i in range(5):
    row.append(defval)
  matrix.append(row)

matrix[3][2]["val"] = True
```

Comment: you append `defval` into all entries of the matrix. Thus, there is just a single dict in memory that is referenced by all entries. When you update the dict, all entries are "updated" as they all reference the same dict. 
try `row.append({"val": False})` instead (I'll post a more detailed answer)

Comment: @LorenzHetterich Tkanks for the explanation. .copy() is what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior arises due to variables in python being passed by reference rather than by value. For example:

```
some_dict = {'foo': 'bar'}
other_dict = some_dict # actually references the same object as some_dict
other_dict['foo'] = 'buzz' # update applies to the dictionary object being referenced
print(other_dict) # {'foo': 'buzz'}
print(some_dict) # {'foo': 'buzz'}
```

Therefore all elements in your matrix actually reference the same dictionary object, and when it is updated, the change is reflected in all references. To avoid this, you can use dictionary's [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) method, which returns a shallow copy of a dictionary. So, your code could look something like this:

```
defval = {
  "val": False
}

matrix = []

for x in range(5):
  row = []
  for i in range(5):
    row.append(defval.copy())
  matrix.append(row)

matrix[3][2]["val"] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `row.append(defval)`, python will not copy the dict stored in `defval`, but will store a reference to the dict in the array.
Thus, all rows implicitly use the same array. When you modify the entry, all rows are modified since they all reference the same dict.

A similar example is given in the following code:

```
blah = [1]
some_list = [blah, blah]
some_list[0][0] = 2
print(some_list)
# [[2], [2]]
print(blah)
# [2]

blah_1 = [1]
blah_2 = [1]
some_list_2 = [blah_1 , blah_2]
some_list_2[0][0] = 2
print(some_list_2)
# [[2], [1]]
print(blah_1)
# [2]
print(blah_2)
# [1]
```